# beam search language translation pytorch

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

I want beam search code for making language translation PyTorch, I want to use it with sample code in this link.

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/translation_transformer.html

Because this link is only presented how to greedy decode in the translation process.